# Как узнать имя метода следующего после объявления некоторой структуры данных

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте, сегодня наткнулся на интересный Ruby гем `Contracts`, как он работает и его исходный код можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/egonSchiele/contracts.ruby).
И у меня появился вопрос, как это гем достает имя следующего после `Contract ... => ...` метода, исходный код проекта не дал мне ответов (возможно я не там искал).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cредствами мета-программирования гем вмешивается в процесс определения каждого из инстанс-методов класса.

Обратите внимание на файл lib/contracts/decorators.rb в нем переопределен метод `method_added()`, который вызывается, когда вы определяете метод при помощи конструкции `def`

```
def method_added(name)
  MethodHandler.new(name, false, self).handle
  super
end
```

Метод принимает параметр `name` с именем определяемого метода, вы сначала выполняете контракт и лишь затем вызываете оригинальный метод `super`, который осуществляет определение метода. Если контракт вызовет исключение (`raise`) - до определения метода дело даже не дойдет. Если контракт действительный или его нет, то Module#method_added просто штатно продолжит свою работу.